# In Pandas how can I map a cell in a filtered DataFrame to the corresponding cell in the original?

Tags: python, pandas

In the code below, I need some way to determine the value of `row_num_mapped` such that the assertion `val == val2` is always true. In other words, for a row/column in a filtered subset of `df` I need to map that cell to a row/column in the original `df`. I can use any of the other variables in the calculation.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(0,5,15), 'b': np.random.randint(0,5,15)},
                  index=np.random.randint(0,5,15))
mean = df['b'].mean()
query_string = f'b<{mean}'
subset = df.query(query_string)

x, y = 2, 0
val = subset.iat[x, y]

x_mapped = ???
val2 = df.iat[x_mapped, y]

assert(val == val2)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but is there a need to make the index random as well?  If you omit that and use a default sequential integer index, you can get the relevant row in the original df from `subset.index.values[row_num]`

Comment: @RickM My use case is that I have a GUI that displays a DataFrame and lets the user edit cells. It displays a filtered version and when they edit a cell I need to modify the cell in the original unfiltered DataFrame as well. This needs to work for any input even if they're looking at a DataFrame with weird or duplicate values in the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my final code here for future reference, just a modified version of Rick M's answer.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(0, 5, 15), 'b': np.random.randint(0, 5, 15)},
                  index=np.random.randint(0, 5, 15))

df['_temp_range_index'] = df.reset_index().index

mean = df['b'].mean()
query_string = f'b<{mean}'
subset = df.query(query_string)

filtered_index_map = subset['_temp_range_index'].reset_index(drop=True)
df.drop('_temp_range_index', axis=1, inplace=True)

x, y = 2, 0
val = subset.iat[x, y]

x_mapped = filtered_index_map[x]
val2 = df.iat[x_mapped, y]

assert (val == val2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a temporary sequential index to the original dataframe, and then kill it afterwards:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(0,5,15), 'b': np.random.randint(0,5,15)},
                  index=np.random.randint(0,5,15))

df = df.set_index(pd.Series(np.arange(len(df)), name='_magicindex'), append=True)

mean = df['b'].mean()
query_string = f'b<{mean}'
subset = df.query(query_string)

x, y = 2, 0
val = subset.iat[x, y]

x_mapped = subset.index.get_level_values('_magicindex')[x]
val2 = df.iat[x_mapped, y]

assert(val == val2)
df = df.droplevel('_magicindex')
```